# Android Studio FirebaseRecyclerAdapter Filter Only Once

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am making an app and I am having a problem displaying items in my recyclerview. I am displaying items with the following configuration in my FirebaseRecyclerAdapter,

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<postsGetInfo, postsGetInfoViewHolder>(postsGetInfo.class, R.layout.posts_layout,postsGetInfoViewHolder.class,OrderByVotes) {
```

The problem that I am having is with my database reference,

```
 OrderByVotes = feedRef.child(current_user_id).orderByChild("displayvotes");
```

As you see, I am ordering each of the items in my recyclerview by the amount of votes. The problem is that when a user upvotes an item it will zoom to the top as I have set it to order by displayvotes. I want it to initially display the items in order of votes and then when a user upvotes the post for it to stay in the same place and not move around.

To Clarify:

- I want the items to filtered by votes and displayed accordingly.
- I then want to remove the filter, `orderByChild("displayvotes");`
- Finally this will order the items initially and then will remove any filter.

I have tried changing `OrderByVotes` in the `OnPopulateViewHolder` but it doesn't work. If somebody can point me in the right direction that would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this question, I have found a solution. It isn't perfect but it works. I firstly made a copy of the feedRef and used that copy to order by displayvotes while still updating the feedRef every time an item is up or down voted. I displayed the votes with my clone database reference, allowing me to vote without movement of items yet still display the votes accordingly.